# React with Google Analytics, shall we truncate url in order to group by them?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I am using `react-ga` to approach google analytics. *In order to group the pageviews pages*, currently, when we send the pageview event, we truncate them. Like `/article/content-name/content-id` was truncated to `/article`.

we use the [`pageview`](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgapageviewpath) function inside `react-ga`, I think we probably can pass in the 2nd parameter(trackerNames) or event 3rd parameter(title) to facilitate grouping pageviews. Just want to verify if it is the right approach, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and it's the way we do it usually.